# Ubuntu 22.04: Shutdown is sometimes delayed

Tags: gnome, shutdown, gnome-shell, gnome-session

```
Kernel: 6.2.0-26-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: GNOME 42.9
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
```

I shutdown my system by pressing the power button. Since i disabled the "confirmation prompt", it usually shuts down immediatelly. But sometimes the shutdown-prompt is shown and shutdown is delayed until 30s timeout is reached.

After taking a look in the journal log, the problem seems to be related with "Client19" not replying.

```
Aug 10 01:55:31 p-Desktop-R7 gnome-shell[2301]: endSessionDialog: No XDG_SESSION_ID, fetched from logind: 2
Aug 10 01:55:31 p-Desktop-R7 systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 10 01:55:31 p-Desktop-R7 at-spi2-registr[2425]: Unable to register client with session manager
Aug 10 01:55:31 p-Desktop-R7 at-spi2-registr[2425]: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.SessionManager.AlreadyRegistered: Unable to register client
Aug 10 01:55:31 p-Desktop-R7 gnome-session-binary[2270]: Entering running state
Aug 10 01:55:31 p-Desktop-R7 gnome-session-binary[2270]: WARNING: Failed to get delay inhibitor: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
Aug 10 01:55:31 p-Desktop-R7 gnome-session[2270]: gnome-session-binary[2270]: WARNING: Failed to get delay inhibitor: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
Aug 10 01:55:31 p-Desktop-R7 gnome-shell[2301]: endSessionDialog: No XDG_SESSION_ID, fetched from logind: 2
Aug 10 01:55:31 p-Desktop-R7 gnome-session-binary[2270]: WARNING: Client '/org/gnome/SessionManager/Client19' failed to reply before timeout
Aug 10 01:55:31 p-Desktop-R7 gnome-session[2270]: gnome-session-binary[2270]: WARNING: Client '/org/gnome/SessionManager/Client19' failed to reply before timeout
Aug 10 01:55:30 p-Desktop-R7 systemd-logind[918]: Power key pressed.
```

Checking the process id of client19 says:

```
/usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
```

How can i fix this problem. Do you need more information?